# Why doesn't react-helmet update the og meta tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make dynamic og. That is, I have a detailed page with news on my site. And when you send a link to this page, it should form og. Here is my code.

```
<Helmet>
      <title>{info && info.title}</title>
      <meta property="og:title" content={info && info.title}/>
      <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
      <meta property="og:description" content={info && info.title}/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="....."/>
      <meta property="og:image" content={info && info.avatar}/>
      <meta property="og:image:url" content={info && info.avatar}/>
      <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg"/>
</Helmet>
```

On the site itself, everything appears in the head, but for some reason, when I pass the link, there is nothing (no photo, no description)

Answer (score 0):

You might need SSR like NextJS, Remix or Vite SSR plugin, since what you're doing only updates the head on the SECOND render or even later instead of first one.

If you observe what your server returns in the initial HTML document you'll see that the meta tags are not there. They appear as soon as react is loaded.